# Finding maxiumum in a group with a single select

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have a group of children for each parent, and a date for each child, all in one table. I'd like to: for each parent, find children with max date. I wrote a statement which does just that:

```
create table t(
  parent string,
  child string,
  date date,
);
```

primary key: (parent, child)

```
select a.*
from
    (select parent, child, date from t) a
  join
    (select parent, max(date) as lastdate from t group by parent) b
  on
    a.parent = b.parent
    and a.date = b.lastdate
```

Now problem is, I do 2 separate selects on table t. Let's say table t is **huge** and I'd like to do this with just one select on table t. Is that possible?

I'm using Oracle SQl Developer on Oracle 10g EE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the aggregate function [`FIRST`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions065.htm#i1000901):

```
SELECT parent, 
       MAX(child) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY date DESC) lastchild, 
       MAX(date) lastdate 
  FROM t
 GROUP BY parent
```

The `lastchild` column will return the value of `child` for the row that has the maximum `date` for this parent. In case of tie (several children have the same max `date`), `MAX` will be applied.

Answer (score 0):

As you are needing to capture all children with the same max date, if I read your original question correctly.  The rank operator will rank all children with the same date as the same rank.  I changed your table slightly so it would work and not conflict with Oracle keywords.

```
    create table t(
  parent varchar2(20),
  child varchar2(20),
  child_date date
);

insert into t (parent, child, child_date) values (1,'A',sysdate-1);
insert into t (parent, child, child_date) values (1,'B',sysdate+45);

insert into t (parent, child, child_date) values (2,'A',sysdate+45);
insert into t (parent, child, child_date) values (2,'B',sysdate+45);

select parent, child from (
    select parent, child, rank() over (partition by parent order by child_date desc) rnk
    from t)
    where rnk = 1;
```